# Linux: is there a read or recv from socket with timeout?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

How can I try to read data from socket with timeout?
I know, select, pselect, poll, has a timeout field, but using of them disables "tcp fast-path" in tcp reno stack.

The only idea I have is to use recv(fd, ..., MSG_DONTWAIT) in a loop

Comment: There is also an option of using threads :) but thread signals still needed

Answer (score 243, accepted):

You can use the [setsockopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt) function to set a timeout on receive operations:

> **SO_RCVTIMEO**
>
> Sets the timeout value that specifies
>   the maximum amount of time an input
>   function waits until it completes. It
>   accepts a timeval structure with the
>   number of seconds and microseconds
>   specifying the limit on how long to
>   wait for an input operation to
>   complete. If a receive operation has
>   blocked for this much time without
>   receiving additional data, it shall
>   return with a partial count or errno
>   set to [EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK] if no
>   data is received. The default for this
>   option is zero, which indicates that a
>   receive operation shall not time out.
>   This option takes a timeval structure.
>   Note that not all implementations
>   allow this option to be set.

```
// LINUX
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = timeout_in_seconds;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

// WINDOWS
DWORD timeout = timeout_in_seconds * 1000;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof timeout);

// MAC OS X (identical to Linux)
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = timeout_in_seconds;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);
```

[Reportedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45957704/1424877) on Windows this should be done before calling `bind`. I have verified by experiment that it can be done either before or after `bind` on Linux and OS X.

Comment: This answer saved my ass.  I was stuck implementing that convoluted "select" crap, with no success.  This worked immediately, so much simpler.

Comment: Now that is why timeout on windows is not working because I am using the code for linux. Thanks. If windows is not using `struct timeval tv;` then does it mean select() wont work too? I tried porting my select() code to windows and it just timeouts immediately it looks like its ignoring the value I am setting at timeval.

Comment: I set timeout value to 5 secs. Why does it always take 5 seconds for each reading cycle regardless there is incoming data or not?

Comment: this also works on windows even after bind operation. tried on windows 10

Comment: can this result in loosing udp packages, eg when the timeout just kicks in when a new message is received?

Comment: @user463035818 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776408/1910445) claims it shouldn't.

Answer (score 28):

Here's some simple code to add a time out to your `recv` function using `poll` in C:

```
struct pollfd fd;
int ret;

fd.fd = mySocket; // your socket handler 
fd.events = POLLIN;
ret = poll(&fd, 1, 1000); // 1 second for timeout
switch (ret) {
    case -1:
        // Error
        break;
    case 0:
        // Timeout 
        break;
    default:
        recv(mySocket,buf,sizeof(buf), 0); // get your data
        break;
}
```

Comment: this would not work exactly as expected. `poll` will wait for receiving at least one byte or timeout, whereas when calling the `recv` function it will wait for `sizeof(buf)` bytes, causing it to block again if this count has not yet arrived, but this time without having a timeout.

Comment: Looking at <https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html> and <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv>, `recv` should return any amount of data available up to `sizeof(buf)` bytes. So this solution should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

// works also after bind operation for WINDOWS

```
DWORD timeout = timeout_in_seconds * 1000;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Install a handler for `SIGALRM`, then use `alarm()` or `ualarm()` before a regular blocking `recv()`.  If the alarm goes off, the `recv()` will return an error with `errno` set to `EINTR`.

Comment: alarms (and signals) are the wrong way to this task. If I want to use tcp fast path, than I need minimal latency. Signals are slow.

Comment: @osgx The signal only occurs if there's a timeout.

Answer (score -3):

**LINUX**

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 30;        // 30 Secs Timeout
tv.tv_usec = 0;        // Not init'ing this can cause strange errors
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
```

**WINDOWS**

```
DWORD timeout = SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT_SEC * 1000;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

**NOTE**: You have put this setting before `bind()` function call for proper run

Comment: This question has already been answered years ago. What new value does your solution bring?

Comment: You have put this setting before bind() function call for proper run this part is not mention in ans