# recv() is not interrupted by a signal in multithreaded environment

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads, signals

I have a thread that sits in a blocking `recv()` loop and I want to terminate (assume this can't be changed to `select()` or any other asynchronous approach).

I also have a signal handler that catches `SIGINT` and theoretically it should make `recv()` return with error and `errno` set to `EINTR`.

But it doesn't, which I assume has something to do with the fact that the application is multi-threaded. There is also another thread, which is meanwhile waiting on a `pthread_join()` call.

What's happening here?

**EDIT:**

OK, now I explicitly deliver the signal to all blocking `recv()` threads via `pthread_kill()` from the main thread (which results in the same global `SIGINT` signal handler installed, though multiple invocations are benign). But `recv()` call is still not unblocked.

**EDIT:**

I've written a code sample that reproduces the problem.

1. Main thread connects a socket to a misbehaving remote host that won't let the connection go.
2. All signals blocked.
3. Read thread thread is started.
4. Main unblocks and installs handler for `SIGINT`.
5. Read thread unblocks and installs handler for `SIGUSR1`.
6. Main thread's signal handler sends a `SIGUSR1` to the read thread.

Interestingly, if I replace `recv()` with `sleep()` it is interrupted just fine.

PS

Alternatively you can just open a UDP socket instead of using a server.

### client

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void
err(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    abort();
}

static void
blockall()
{
    sigset_t ss;
    sigfillset(&ss);
    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, NULL))
        err("pthread_sigmask");
}

static void
unblock(int signum)
{
    sigset_t ss;
    sigemptyset(&ss);
    sigaddset(&ss, signum);
    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &ss, NULL))
        err("pthread_sigmask");
}

void
sigusr1(int signum)
{
    (void)signum;
    printf("%lu: SIGUSR1\n", pthread_self());
}

void*
read_thread(void *arg)
{
    int sock, r;
    char buf[100];

    unblock(SIGUSR1);
    signal(SIGUSR1, &sigusr1);
    sock = *(int*)arg;
    printf("Thread (self=%lu, sock=%d)\n", pthread_self(), sock);
    r = 1;
    while (r > 0)
    {
        r = recv(sock, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
        printf("recv=%d\n", r);
    }
    if (r < 0)
        perror("recv");
    return NULL;
}

int sock;
pthread_t t;

void
sigint(int signum)
{
    int r;
    (void)signum;
    printf("%lu: SIGINT\n", pthread_self());
    printf("Killing %lu\n", t);
    r = pthread_kill(t, SIGUSR1);
    if (r)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(r));
        abort();
    }
}

int
main()
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    printf("main thread: %lu\n", pthread_self());
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (socket < 0)
        err("socket");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        err("inet_pton");
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr))
        err("connect");

    blockall();
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    if (pthread_create(&t, &attr, &read_thread, &sock))
        err("pthread_create");
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    unblock(SIGINT);
    signal(SIGINT, &sigint);

    if (sleep(1000))
        perror("sleep");
    if (pthread_join(t, NULL))
        err("pthread_join");
    if (close(sock))
        err("close");

    return 0;
}
```

### server

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',8888))
s.listen(1)
c = []
while True:
    (conn, addr) =  s.accept()
    c.append(conn)
```

Comment: I'm encountering something similar (while different in some aspect), with a single thread application (a single process without other thread). So I believe multi‑threading is not the cause of the behaviour here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Normally signals do not interrupt system calls with `EINTR`. Historically there were two possible signal delivery behaviors: the BSD behavior (syscalls are automatically restarted when interrupted by a signal) and the Unix System V behavior (syscalls return -1 with `errno` set to `EINTR` when interrupted by a signal). Linux (the kernel) adopted the latter, but the GNU C library developers (correctly) deemed the BSD behavior to be much more sane, and so on modern Linux systems, calling `signal` (which is a library function) results in the BSD behavior.

POSIX allows either behavior, so it's advisable to always use `sigaction` where you can choose to set the `SA_RESTART` flag or omit it depending on the behavior you want. See the documentation for `sigaction` here:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html

Comment: @Alex - So using `sigaction` and setting the `SA_RESTART` flag solved your problem?

Comment: Omitting the `SA_RESTART` flag would give the behavior OP wanted.

Comment: Actually on Linux / Ubuntu 12.04, both behaviours are exposed: `recv` will be restarted on Ctrl-C, while `poll` will return `EINT` on the same Ctrl-C. But using `sigaction` instead of `signal` indeed solve the case. This means `sigaction` is the way to go to get predictable behaviours with signals occurring during system-calls; so it's indeed advisable to always use `sigaction` (I will since now).

Comment: `poll` and `select` are special in that they never restart. This is specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 6):

In a multi-threaded application, normal signals can be delivered to any thread arbitrarily. Use `pthread_kill` to send the signal to the specific thread of interest.

Comment: For some reason this does not work (recv call is not interrupted). Do I need to do anything special to signal handlers and/or signal mask for a thread?

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the signal handler was invoked, and if so, from what thread? Is the signal received after the `recv()` call completes?

Answer (score 4):

Does signal handler invoked in same thread which waits in recv()?
You may need to explicitly mask SIGINT in all other threads via pthread_sigmask()

Comment: Correct - a process-directed signal is delivered to an abitrary thread that doesn't have it blocked, so the solution is to block it in all other threads.

Comment: For sake of completeness: a new thread inherit the signal mask from its parent. You may block it in the parent, and unblock it after the thread creation. It may be the only solution (that I know) if you depend on a library that create threads, which you are unable to change.

Comment: I don't think this works for me. I need the main thread to stop the blocking thread, which means signal handler should be installed in the thread that does not call `recv()`.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in the post by `<R..`>, it is indeed possible to change the signal activities.
I often create my own "signal" function that makes use of sigaction.  Here's what I use

```
typedef void Sigfunc(int);

static Sigfunc* 
_signal(int signum, Sigfunc* func)
{
    struct sigaction act, oact;

    act.sa_handler = func;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (signum != SIGALRM)
        act.sa_flags |= SA_NODEFER; //SA_RESTART;

    if (sigaction(signum, &act, &oact) < 0)
        return (SIG_ERR);
    return oact.sa_handler;
}
```

The attribute in question above is the 'or'ing of the sa_flags field.  This is from the man page for 'sigaction': SA_RESTART provides the BSD-like behavior of allowing system calls to be restartable across signals. SA_NODEFER means allow the signal to be received from within its own signal handler.

When the signal calls are replaced with "_signal", the thread is interrupted.  The output prints out "interrupted system call" and recv returned a -1 when SIGUSR1 was sent.  The program stopped altogether with the same output when SIGINT was sent, but the abort was called at the end.

I did not write the server portion of the code, I just changed the socket type to "DGRAM, UDP" to allow the client to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on Linux recv: [Linux: is there a read or recv from socket with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876024/linux-is-there-a-read-or-recv-from-socket-with-timeout)

When you get a signal, call done on the class doing the receive.

```
void* signalThread( void* ptr )
{
    CapturePkts* cap=(CapturePkts*)ptr;
    sigset_t sigSet=cap->getSigSet();
    int sig=-1;
    sigwait(&sigSet,&sig); //signalThread: signal capture thread enabled;
    cout << "signal=" << sig << " caught,ending process" << endl;
    cap->setDone();
    return 0;
}

class CapturePkts
{
     CapturePkts() : _done(false) {}

     sigset_t getSigSet() { return _sigSet; }

     void setDone() {_done=true;}

     bool receive( uint8_t *buffer, int32_t bufSz, int32_t &nbytes)
     {
         bool ret=true;
         while( ! _done ) {
         nbytes = ::recv( _sockid, buffer, bufSz, 0 );
         if(nbytes < 1 ) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
               nbytes=0; //wait for next read event
            else
               ret=false;
         }
         return ret;
     }

     private:
     sigset_t _sigSet;
     bool _done;
};
```